# How to navigate from one tabpage to another tabpage of tabcontrol in C # using some keyevent

Tags: c#

I want to use key like arrow key or any other alphabet to move tab from one to next and from next to back. Example:
suppose my tabcontrol has 5 tab page, when I am in tab one I immediately want to move to 2 and from second to third and son on. and vice-versa.

Comment: What does this have to do with `SQL Server`?

Comment: seriously, what have you tried on your own..? can you share with us anything, for example; what keyword search did you use when doing your search..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will work after any tab is selected

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication28
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.tabControl1.KeyDown +=new KeyEventHandler(Tab_KeyDown);

        }
        private void Tab_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
            Console.WriteLine(tabControl.SelectedIndex.ToString());
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
            {
                if (tabControl.TabIndex > 0)
                    tabControl.TabIndex  -= 1;
            }
            else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
            {
                int numberOfPages = tabControl.TabPages.Count;
                if (tabControl.TabIndex < numberOfPages - 1)
                    tabControl.TabIndex  += 1;

            }
        }

    }
}
```